# objects rendered as grey without shading etc. how to fix

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

objects on rendered not shows up and in viewport render mode it looks completely gray.
used default project for testing if it works but not works.
you know default start thingy.
[image]

it looks like that.
how i susposed to fix that?
i resetted to factory settings few times but it didn't help.
i can only render in cycles on old versions of blender.(this actually old one
2.80 beta is version.

render looks like this:
[image]

---

**Fixed problem by upgrading newer version of blender**

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: solved by upgrading blender. just change versions it will fix it